# How to declare a type globally in a project (typescript)

Tags: typescript

In a typescript project,
  is there any way to declare a type and share it across all files, in the same way we have access to types defined globally at `node.d.ts`?

For example, let's say that in my project a `IUser` is something such as

```
interface IUser {
   name: string,
   mail: string
 }
```

Ok, I can create that interface in a `common/interfaces.ts` file and import it every time I need it... but would be so nice to be able to declare such interfaces globally for the whole project and have quick access to them without importing any file

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can create a *definition file*, ending with the `.d.ts` extension, and place it in your project where you'd like:

**user.d.ts**

```
interface IUser {
    name: string,
    mail: string
}
```

This is also a good way to fill missing global types. I have a `lib/global` folder per project to place these files.

This only works with type definitions, not actual code, as (1) that actual code would have to be imported some way, (2) `.d.ts` is [ambient](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html). Also, for types defined this way to be globally visible, the corresponding declaration file **should not contain top-level exports** (otherwise the declaration file will be regarded as a *module*, requiring an import to access its types).

---

You can also declare modules:

```
declare module "my-module" {
    export declare class Something {
        public something: number;
    }
}
```

And then TypeScript will allow the following:

```
import { Something } from "my-module";
```

Comment: @Manu -- TypeScript _should_ be able to find it. Are you including this definition file in `tsconfig.json`? (or whatever your setup is, e.g. in Visual Studio it should be added to the project)

Comment: @Manu -- Also, it will only work if the `.d.ts` file is not recognized as a _module_ -- that is, don't use top-level exports in `user.d.ts`.

Comment: what if you need to import a type from a dependency? for example `moment`

Comment: @Manu you can declare a module for that, see my (kinda late) edit.

Comment: "declaration file should not contain top-level exports" was my problem. So hard to find answers to these problems... Many thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to add custom type directory to `"include"` with relative path in `tsconfig.json`. For example: `"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "types/*"
  ]`

Answer (score 11):

Create global.d.ts in your project root.

Here is an example of how to declare global types constants and interfaces that will be understood globally

```
//example import for externally loaded library
//this will not form part of the bundle but will allow typescript to understand external libraries throughout the project
import _ from 'lodash'; 

declare global { 
    //Example global constant for libraries served via webpack externals. example webpack config:: externals: { _: 'lodash' }
    //This assumes lodash was already load in DOM for example in <head> via CDN link before main.js is loaded.
    const _: typeof _; 

    //example of custom types
    type JSONPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null;
    type JSONValue = JSONPrimitive | JSONObject | JSONArray;
    type JSONObject = { [member: string]: JSONValue };

    //example of custom interface
    interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> {}
}
```

Comment: in a module based project you don't need the ```global {}```   just put your ```declare type XXXX``` in the ```_whatever.d.ts``` and make sure it's in your project source folder

Comment: I have no idea about `make sure it's in your project source folder`. Can you give some details about the description above?

Answer (score 9):

You can define types in multiple files and use them in other files. There are two possble ways:

1. The files are using the same namespace. In this case the type can be reused directly.
2. The files are using different namespaces. In this case the reusable type has to be marked with `export`. It can then be used in other namespaces. With the `import` statement you can avoid having to use the namespace prefix.

In any case, you have to add [a reference to the file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) whose types you want to reuse.

**Same namespace**

*File 1:*

```
namespace Example {
    export interface IUser {
       name: string,
       mail: string
    }
}
```

*File 2:*

```
/// <reference path="./File1.ts" />

namespace Example {
    class User implements IUser {
       name: string,
       mail: string
    }
}
```

**Different namespaces**

*File 1:*

```
namespace Example {
    export interface IUser {
       name: string,
       mail: string
    }
}
```

*File 2 (no import):*

```
/// <reference path="./File1.ts" />

class User implements Example.IUser {
   name: string,
   mail: string
}
```

*File 2 (with import):*

```
/// <reference path="./File1.ts" />

import IUser = Example.IUser;

class User implements IUser {
   name: string,
   mail: string
}
```

Comment: question: why not mention the `.d.ts` method? Only because it's in another answer?