# How to declare global typescript interfaces in next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am making an ecommerce web app using next.js and typescript for frontend, in which I have declared many interfaces which are similar in different pages and components. Is there some way I can make global interfaces which can be accessed by all pages and components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a type globally in a project (typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025767/how-to-declare-a-type-globally-in-a-project-typescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think it's a better approach to import the types. But if you want to create the types globally, then you can create a `custom.d.ts` file in the root of your application. Then you can create the types there.

```
    declare global {
      interface User {
        name: string;
        email: string;
      }
    }
```

This will work. But I don't recommend using this.

Comment: Somehow that does not work. I declared it inside the file that gives me TS warning

Comment: create a custom.d.ts file and pasted the code there, it will work, you can create it at the root of your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

@Pranta's answer is correct, but you also need to export at the end.

```
declare global {
    interface User {
        name: string;
        email: string;
    }
}
export default global;
```