Is there a way to extend module augmentations to the package scope when using typescript?
I have a module that comes from an external library that I augment in my application code:
// in 
type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
};

declare module "@some/library" {
    interface LibraryType extends MyType{}
}

this works really well within a module, but I'd like to share this declaration for all the modules in my package. If I move this declare statement to a .d.ts file:
import {
    MyType,
} from "elsewhere";

declare global {
    declare module "@some/library" {
        interface LibraryType extends MyType{}
    }
}

then it stops working (I no longer see a and b on LibraryType). What am I doing wrong?

Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025767/how-to-declare-a-type-globally-in-a-project-typescript

No, this is a different problem. If you check their solution is the same as the problem in my question.

Yeah that's why I just posted it as comment instead of voting to close.
